# How to connect ST7789 LCD to Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, display, spi, screen

I'm trying to connect to [this](https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B07P7W8D8J/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) LCD  ( sry 4 japanese page:( use translate plz )
This monitor driver is ST7789, 7pins.[GND VCC SCL SDA RES DC BLK] And now I'm connecting to pi like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgd2U.jpg

I'm using [Python_ST7789](https://github.com/solinnovay/Python_ST7789) library. The installation was success and The example program is running correctlly, but display is blank. is my wiring incorrect ? is this display garbage?

PS: Sry for my Stup1d English help me plz.

---

(1) [Pimonori 1.3" IPS SPI 240x240 pixel Colour LCD Breakout - £15](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/1-3-spi-colour-lcd-240x240-breakout)

[image: pimoroni lcd]

---

*ST7789 Python Libraries For Rpi*

(1) [solinnovay/Python_ST7789](https://github.com/solinnovay/Python_ST7789) (AdaFruit GPIO, PIL/Pillow, 2018sep)

(2) [pimoroni/st7789-python](https://github.com/pimoroni/st7789-python) (Pimoroni, RPI.GPIO, spidev, 2019sep)

---

*ST7789 LDC Wiring Diagram*

[image: wiring]

---

*ST7789 LCD 7/12 pin Description for troubleshooting*

[image: pin descriptions]

---

*ST7789 7 pin and 12 pin Layout*

[TaoBao ST7789 1.3" TFT IPS LCD Module - ¥18](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z1r.7974869.0.0.269c3ad4bUgyfB&id=586107635433)

[image: 7/12pin layout]

---

*ST7789 LCD Wiring For Second Screen Using SPI Chip Select CS1*

[How to connect ST7789 LCD to SPI Bus 1 as 2nd screen?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104846/how-to-connect-st7789-lcd-to-spi-bus-1-as-2nd-screen)

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100876/discussion-on-question-by-ichirow-how-to-connect-st7789-lcd-to-raspberry-pi).

Answer (score 1):

I've same display. I've changed in clock_EN.py:

```
# Raspberry Pi pin configuration:
RST = 27
DC  = 25
LED = 24
```

in

```
# Raspberry Pi pin configuration:
RST = 25
DC  = 24
LED = 27
```

... and now it works