# Raspberry pi with 1.3" oled i2c screen

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+, i2c, adafruit

I'm currently trying to use this 1.3" i2c oled screen with the Adafruit oled i2c library, but I'm currently getting this issue:

[image]
I have made sure to run the setup.py and all of the code is the same.

The screen is a GME12864-80

Is there any way that I can fix this?

Comment: It looks like you have the wrong screen size (pixels width x height) setting.

Comment: I googled but could not find the spec.  Can you give me a link?

Comment: @tlfong01 don't worry about it anymore, I've decided to go with a much more well known screen, as I too couldn't find a proper spec for it

Comment: @danwillm, OK. I recommend this one: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105364/how-to-connect-st7789-lcd-to-raspberry-pi

Comment: @tlfong01 thanks! I'll look into it!

Comment: @danwillm, Your are welcome. Yesterday I successfully installed the Pimoroni st7789 LCD python library (see chat record).  Next step is to do programming. I found Pimoroni softwre well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the driver you are using is not the correct one for the screen, I had the same problem and changing the driver from SSD1306 to SH1106, and it worked correctly.
https://luma-oled.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
regards,