# Need to display 2 LCDS at 800x480

Tags: raspbian, lcd

Im using a Raspberry Pi 4 running the latest version of Raspbian.

I need to run 2 separate 5" LCD displays at 800x480.

This is the LCD I'm using: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1680, connected through this board: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2218

I've tried modifying `config.txt` to change resolution, but this only changes HDMI 1 to 800x480 and leaves HDMI 2 at the regular resolution.

Comment: Hi @DekkoWolfe, Welcome. Please give us a link to your 2.5" LCD.

Comment: Just edited post to clarify, I am using two separate 5" LCD screens. However, here is a link to the screens I am using (Both the same) https://www.adafruit.com/product/1680

Comment: Ah, your 5" mon is RGB TTL and has an unusual 40 pin connector.  I think it is NOT HDMI, and therefore NOT compatible to Rpi.  For cheapie small 0.9" to 3.5" LCD/LED monitors with or without touch screen, you might like to consider SPI/I2C interface monitors, such as this.  (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105364/how-to-connect-st7789-lcd-to-raspberry-pi.

Comment: I seem to also have forgotten to mention that I am using this board to connect the LCDs to the Pi https://www.adafruit.com/product/2218 (I posted this before going to bed, probably not the best idea)

Comment: Ah your update info makes every thing clear now. Cheers.

Comment: If I read this in a year, what is then the latest version of Raspbian?