# how do I mirror my google maps from phone to a small display on raspberry pi , {of course without GPS module}?

Tags: raspbian

So, I am looking to make a very simple device that can work as a secondary screen for the maps app on my phone so that I can attach it to my bike and see the direction with having to use a cellphone holder.

The maps will use the GPS from the phone and will transmit the direction to the pi's display. and the communication will be over Bluetooth.

thanks for the help.

Comment: For the secondary screen, you can use any small screen like this one: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105364/how-to-connect-st7789-lcd-to-raspberry-pi, (2) Rpi BlueTooth BlueZ5.x is still buggy, so perhaps you can use a cheapie GPS module and use Rpi GPSD to get more useful data direct from GSP module: 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/rpi-uart-to-gps-module-connection-problem.

Comment: The reason I dont want to have a gps module is the I want to keep it really light weight , in terms of processing, complexity and literally.

Comment: I agree with you that space and weight are important factors to trade off.  But human time, I mean unreliable, often intermittently Bluetooth pairing but then disconnecting time wasting problem is a always problem that won't go away. Anyway, I am waiting for perhaps one more year for coming Rpi5 and BT6 to smooth out things. Cheers.

Comment: Hope ! .Working on it !

Comment: I would be very glad and grateful if you can help solving the Rpi3/4 BlueZ5x teething problem.  Cheers.

Comment: I'll keep you posted, 