# ST7789 Display on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: python, display, wiring

I just got an ST7789 240x240 display and i can't get it to work with my PI.

i'm using this library: https://github.com/DjamesSuhanko/Python_ST7789

i installed all the python dependency's

When i try to run the example it gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clock_EN.py", line 39, in 
    mode=SPI_MODE, rst=RST, dc=DC, led=LED)
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'spi'

My wiring is as the following:

7789 Display <-> Raspberry Pi (PIN# as BOARD, not BCM)
GND <----------> PIN# 6
VCC <----------> PIN# 16
SCL <----------> PIN# 23
SDA <----------> PIN# 19
RES <----------> PIN# 13 
DC <----------> PIN# 22
BLK <----------> PIN# 18

[image: Reference]

I'm sure the spi is enabled in config.txt on the root

Comment: Try this https://github.com/pimoroni/st7789-python which is known to work (using CE0 by default). https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi shows the pins you need to connect.

Comment: The following might help: (1) How to connect ST7789 LCD to Raspberry Pi
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105364/how-to-connect-st7789-lcd-to-raspberry-pi

(2) How to connect ST7789 LCD to SPI Bus 1 as 2nd screen?
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104846/how-to-connect-st7789-lcd-to-spi-bus-1-as-2nd-screen. Cheers.

Comment: You are going to have to look at `clock_EN.py` and check line 39. What the option `spi` is or where it gets called from. The init function get `spi` keyword as parameter and doesn't know what to do with it. EDIT: did you change the source files? It looks good on github